# C# equivalent of PowerShell $input variable

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am creating PowerShell cmdlets in C# by extending the PSCmdlet class.
I need to get the entire Pipelined input to use in the C# code. I tried having a parameter with properties set as:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline = true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true)]
public Object Connection;
```

When I try to execute the cmdlet by piping in a list of items, I get one item at a time to process in the C# code.

```
$a=@("value1","value2")
$a | cmdlet-name
```

I need to get the entire piped input to process in my C# code. I found that this can be obtained in PowerShell using the $input variable. Is there a C# equivalent of this $input PowerShell variable?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of.  However, you can use the ProcessRecord method to accumulate pipeline objects (from the property bound to pipeline input) into a collection and then process the accumulated objects in your EndProcessing method.

Comment: I am not sure but is it that for each pipelined item the ProcessRecord method is executed once? if yes, is there a way to find out the current pass number of the ProcessRecord method?

Comment: Yes ProcessRecord is executed for each pipeline object.  Keep in mind that a single pipeline object could be an array depending on how you define your property that is pipeline bound.  I'm not aware of a built-in way to determine the pass number but you can always add an int field to your cmdlet and increment it each time ProcessRecord gets called.